# Show that if $n\log(a_n) \rightarrow 1$, then $a_n \rightarrow 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $n\log(a_n) \rightarrow 1$. Show that $a_n \rightarrow 1$.

*Background:* On page 58 of the book *Asymptopia* by Spencer and Florescu, it is mentioned that if $\log A(n)=o(1)$, then $A(n) \sim 1$. I couldn't prove it.

**Edit:** Dear downvoters, I realize that $\log A(n)=o(1) \implies A(n) \sim 1$ is ridiculously easy to prove. I didn't think much about it once I started trying the question I posted. I do think that the *actual question that I posted* isn't *obvious*, without the observation that $\log(a_n) \sim 1/n = o(1)$ and hence $a_n \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Continuity of the exponential function at $x = 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I have corrected the question

Comment: It would be helpful if the person who downvoted can tell why.

Comment: OK, that's better. If $\log a_n = 1/n + o(1/n)$, can you infer something about $a_n$? People these days would like you to show some more effort. (I did not downvote, but I think you might be able to make some reasonable efforts here.)

Comment: @MathewsBoban I didn't downvote but you'll find that if you post a question without showing your work and effort on the question, it will not be well received in this forum.

Comment: I might have thought the typo in the original question (i.e., the missing $\log$) was the issue, but now there is another downvote, so apparently that was irrelevant to those downvoters.

Comment: @HansEngler, can you give some more information? One way of using what you said gives $a_n^n \rightarrow e$, which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @TedShifrin, if $\log a_n = 1/n + o(1/n)$, then, $a_n \rightarrow 1$. It didn't occur to me that $f(n) \sim g(n)$ is equivalent to $f(n) = g(n) + o(g(n))$. I only tried to work with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)/g(n) = 1$, and couldn't make much progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\log a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}(n \log a_n)\frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} n \log a_n\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 1\cdot 0 = 0$$

Since $\exp$ is continuous at $0$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n =1$